# Working to create large prints dpi and size?

Tags: print-design, dpi, scale

I need to create a 11400mm X 3300mm size print in photoshop.
What settings can I use that won't completely slow down my computer?
For example I tried to create a doc 11400mm X 3300mm @ 300dpi but it was way too large to work with.

Could I create a new doc in PS at 114mm X 33mm @ 300 dpi that the printer will resize to 11400 X 3300 and it would still look good printed?

ps I have to work with Photos and not vectors

Sorry if this is a stupid question :)

Answer (score -1):

At first you complete your work with **114mm X 33mm @ 300 dpi**  and then finally click **alt + ctrl + I** to resize **11400 X 3300** 
[image]

Done!!